# Listing all current events using EWS Managed API

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

Our organization has an Exchange server, where each employee has a calendar. We want to make an application showing a list with the current event for every user. Is this possible using the EWS Managed API?

We also want to add a special icon whenever a user has a birthday. Can I somehow store and retrieve birthdays via Exchange, or do I need to create a birthday config file for my application only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Answer to  your first question "Yes" it is possible using the Managed API.
2. Yes you can store and retrieve birthdays via extended properties if the calendar doesnt already have one.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I needed to know.

Comment: You are welcome I'm glad I could help I have developed an Exchange Managed API windows service and learned a lot from it. Anything else let me know.